# Angular2 - set initial value in select - Reactive forms

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a problem with setting default option in select. I am getting array from server and I want to select second item in array which is documentTypes[1]. Here's my code and what I tried to do.

**Select HTML**

```
<select formControlName="type">
    <option *ngFor="let document of documentTypes" [ngValue]="document" [attr.selected]="selectedType">{{document.name | translate}}</option>
</select>
```

**Values from server**

```
getDocumentTypes() {
    this._api.send(urlValues.documentType, 'Get').subscribe(
        res => {
            this.selectedType = res.content.types[1];
            this.documentTypes = res.content.types;
        },
        err => console.log(err)
    );
}
```

**I also have build document method and I tried this**

```
buildDocument(document?: any) {
    if (document) {
        this.documentForm = this._fb.group({
            customer: this._fb.group({
                oib: document.customer.oib,
                location: document.customer.location
            }),
            payment_method: document.payment_method,
            delivery_method: document.delivery_method,
            status: document.status,
            type: document.type,
            expiration_date: document.expiration_date,
            delivery_date: document.delivery_date,
            note: document.note
        });
    } else {
        this.documentForm = this._fb.group({
            customer: this._fb.group({
                oib: null,
                location: null
            }),
            payment_method: null,
            delivery_method: null,
            status: null,
            type: this.documentTypes[1],
            expiration_date: '',
            delivery_date: '',
            note: ''
        });
    }
}
```

Do you have any other solutions? Thanks

Comment: A plunkr would be very useful.

Comment: That is `if(document) {` for? Is the 2nd (else) branch event executed?

Comment: If(document) is for editing form, when I get existing document data and fill the form, I just call buildDocument(document) @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: I would use an ngModel for the selected value in the select.

Comment: You don't need to replicate your code. Just set your form to a empty model. When editing, you populate your empty model as document. Concerning your initial issue, could you show us the method that retrieve data from database ?

Comment: @mickdev I just want to set initial value for this select, method is up there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of the formControl instead of having `[attr.selected]`. Perhaps you also need to use e.g `patchValue`, since data is async and set the preselected value after data has been retrieved, so that your app won't throw an error when trying to build the form if data is not present.

So your select would look something like this:

```
<select name="document" formControlName="type">
    <option *ngFor="let doc of documentTypes" [value]="doc.name">  
        {{doc.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

And when you have received data from the API, you can use `patchValue`:

```
  this.documentForm
    .patchValue({
        type: this.documentTypes[1].name
    })
```

Here's a **[demo plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RYu8S2DuDUe0WzYQ9RSy?p=preview)**, where `Set Value` button sort of simulates that data is coming async, just to showcase the `patchValue` :)

**PS:**

You can use `ngValue` if you need to bind the whole object, but that also means that your form value will contain the whole object, similar to this:

```
{
  "type": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Doc 2"
  }
}
```

and maybe that is not what you want, so I'm using just the `name` here, so your form value looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "Doc 3"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
getDocumentTypes() {
    this._api.send(urlValues.documentType, 'Get').subscribe(
        res => {
            this.selectedType = res.content.types[1];
            this.documentTypes = res.content.types;
            this. documentForm.patchValue({'type': res.content.types[1]}, {onlySelf: true}) //Add this line
        },
        err => console.log(err)
    );
```

}